# How to limit the user access to a directory in external drive?

Tags: permissions, ssh, git, raspberrypi, chown

I have a Raspberry pi 4 with Ubuntu Server 20.04 LTS  installed.
There, i have a Git repository hosting (precarious) for my personal projects, but i'm trying to use it for a team project. The Git directory are in an external drive, and the users do git pushing through ssh, by a Ubuntu user called git.
I want to know how to do the ssh auth with the git user in /home/git/.ssh but that the user can only write on /home/git/repos (repos is a link to /media/hhd, an external hard disc).
I want to do that to prevent the external users writing in the internal sdcard, but yes in the external drive.

I sorry for my English, i don't speak English but i'm using what i learned at school.

Answer (score 0):

The best is to use some additional software that manage auth/access for you git repo.

gitolite  https://gitolite.com/gitolite/index.html

gitosis   https://github.com/tv42/gitosis , the projet is dead

Or if you want more , gitlab is opensource so you can install on your PI

Comment: Thank you for your response, i'll be reading about these projects.